# PHP codeigniter Session value lost when refreshed in the WAMP server

Tags: php, codeigniter

My php program is aimed to purchase some products and add them to a cart. So I have set a session array in the model and it keeps the details of the products, total count etc. This code works exactly fine in localhost. But the session is lost in my server when the page is refreshed, and as a result the session array only able to keep the details of the last added product, Every time a new product is added, the previous data are lost. I m using WAMP server. Can anyone help Me??

Thanks..

Comment: CI stores session data either in a db, or in a cookie. Can you confirm what you have that option set to?

Comment: Its in cookie. Does that affect?

Answer (score 0):

I think Its becasuse the info u are storing in session its being  replaced by new one....
Best Way I can Suggest you is Use Codeigniter's Inbuilt shopping Class Its really amazing.
ANd If u are not Using DB to store session Use Native session Library coz Codigniter Session is by default stored in cookie And which Limit the stored size upto 4kb..

I just Implemented The Shopping Cart Last week Using Above libray and shopping Cart Class

Comment: Thanks. But it works in localhost. So is there any settings to be done  in the server regarding session...

Comment: if (isset($sess_arr["count"]) == 0) 
                {

Comment: OKay...I think i got u r problem...Its bcz of name of u r seesion may conflict with another sessions name on server....
Just Do one thing add some prfix in your sesion name... say cart_YoyrSessionname

Comment: just post the code wen u r initialising the seesion like...$this->sesssion->set_userdata($array);

Comment: $sess_arr = $this->session->userdata('cart');                     if (isset($sess_arr["count"]) == 0)                             $this->session->set_userdata("cart", array('count' => 1,'amount' => $details["price"]));                                               if (isset($sess_arr["count"]) > 0)                                                   $this->session->set_userdata("cart", array('count' => $cart_cnt,'amount' => $sess_arr["amount"]));                                     //The variables declarations are omitted... Sorry for the error in the previous code

Comment: have u tried by adding prefix....Just Take on varibale $pre=abc and append it in every seesion name like

$this->session->set_userdata("$pre.cart", array('$pre.count' => 1,'$pre.amount' => $details["price"]))